# NPE in nodetool refresh

Tags: cassandra, database-migration, nodetool

I'm migrating data from Cassandra 1.1.3 to 1.2.13. I created snapshots of column families and move all the data inside them to each column family directories of new nodes.

Then ran nodetool's `upgradesstables -a` command.
Then I ran `refresh <KS> <CF>` command and then I get following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Table.createReplicationStrategy(Table.java:278)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Table.<init>(Table.java:263)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Table.open(Table.java:109)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Table.open(Table.java:87)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.loadNewSSTables(ColumnFamilyStore.java:468)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.loadNewSSTables(StorageService.java:3861)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:93)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:27)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:208)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(PerInterface.java:120)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(MBeanSupport.java:264)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:762)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1454)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:74)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1394)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:818)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:303)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

What is wrong here?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was due to a version incompatibility between Cassandra and nodetool.